# Could my pc's mac address be guessed and thereby stored by websites?

Tags: ip, mac-address

If I don't use a vpn, should I disable IPv6 to avoid my pc's mac address be guessed ?
While paying online, once I saw a bill that included my IPv6, should I be concerned at all?

Comment: I know this is not an exact duplicate, but it answers your underlying question: what are the risks of exposing your MAC?

Comment: @schroeder - Thanks. Should I delete this in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You should enable [privacy settings for IPv6](https://www.internetsociety.org/resources/deploy360/2014/privacy-extensions-for-ipv6-slaac/), so that you use a pseudo generated IP, and not one based on the MAC of the computer. On Windows this appears to be the default, although I have never studied IP allocation on Windows in detail with IPv6.

IPv6 can indeed increase privacy through the use of ephemeral addresses that are short-lived.

As with all technology, you need to understand it and quantify the risks.

Comment: The link says - You are being followed as the IPv6 addresses are unique, that's scary. By default, all os' must generate a pseudo IP.